# Tkinter search: Need to search for every text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function which adds a text widget to the frame dynamically when a user clicks a button. And then different text is inserted into each of the text widget. These text widgets have been stored in a list because I want to scroll all the text box by calling the `.see` method.

I have a function defined which auto-scrolls all the text widget to a specific position which is obtained using the `text.search()` method.

the `text.search()` methods returns the index for the search-term from the text widget no. 1 of the frame, and then it auto-scrolls all the text widget.

***Question***

How to search for a specific term individually in all text_widgets and obtain their indexes and use their indexes to scroll their respective text boxes?

***Similar code***

```
#Initializing an array at the top of your code:

widgets = []

#Next, add each text widget to the array:

for i in range(10):
    text1 = tk.Text(...)
    widgets.append(text1)

#Next, define a function that calls the see method on all of the widgets:

def autoscroll(pos):
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.see(pos)

#Finally, adjust your binding to call this new method:

pos_start = text1.search(anyword, '1.0', "end")
text1.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda e, index=pos_start: autoscroll(index))
```

Comment: You do it just like the scrolling: iterate over the list of widgets.

Comment: At least provide an MCVE

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple to do.

I don't understand, however, why you are performing the search before the activate the auto-scroll functionality. All you need to do is cycle through the `list` `widgets` and determine where the text appears whenever you want to start the autoscroll, the below script will perform what I believe to be the desired behaviour:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.texts = [tk.Text(self.root) for i in range(3)]
        for i in self.texts:
            i.pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Find 'foobar'", command=self.find).pack()

    def find(self):
        for i in self.texts:
            if i.search("foobar", "1.0", "end") != "":
                i.see(i.search("foobar", "1.0", "end"))

root = tk.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, this does not take in to account multiple results for the search term within the same `Text` widget or even in multiple `Text` widgets.